# Convert a HashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> to HashMap<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashset

I would like to convert a `HashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>` to `HashMap<String, List<String>>` so that I can print all their indexes.

I would like to store only the distinct values from a list of 'String's that start with a letter.

e.g. 
I have this list (listOfFruits):

```
a.apple
c.banana
b.orange
c.mango
b.pear
a.lemon
b.orange
c.mango
c.apple
```

and I would like this output:

```
a.1
c.1
b.1
c.2
b.2
a.2
b.1
c.3
c.2
```

This means:

- in box (a) I have 2 objects with index 1 and 2,
- in box (b) I have 1 object with index 1 and 1,
- in box (c) I have 3 objects with index 1, 2, 2 and 3

I thought I could put them in a HashMap to find the distinct fruits and then convert it into a list to get their index.

```
HashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> myMap1 = new HashMap<>();
for (String string.split("\\.")[0] : listOfFruits) {
     myMap1.computeIfAbsent(string , k -> new LinkedHashSet<()).add(string.split("\\.")[1]);
}
```

Am I approaching it correctly?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The output doesn't seem to match your explanation?

Comment: This is just a possible step that I thought of. I would use the result of `myMap1` to have all the fruits in order without their duplicates just so that I could find their index with the conversion that I am wondering about.

Comment: No I meant your example doesn't seem to make sense. "In box (b) you have 1 object with index 1 **and** 1?" Do you have 2 or 1 objects?

Comment: Since in box (b) there exists only orange (it is just displayed twice), all I need is to count it once. I think of it like an error that is displayed twice erroneously.

Comment: What is the map ? Please give example for key/value, and detail more please